# Spring boot JPA query timeout issue

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

Using JHipster / Spring Boot: I am having an issue where a request for a large amount of data is returning 503 after exactly 30 seconds. This seems to be stemming from the database read.

Tried setting 5 min timeout here:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 300)
public class OrderQueryService extends QueryService<Order> {
```

Checked that `max_execution_time = 0` on mysql server

Any ideas on how I could allow for a longer execution time on these queries?

Comment: What do you mean by a large amount of data? 1 million rows? I would rather start by looking at the query execution plan to see whether your query needs an index. Put Hibernate in debug or use datasource-proxy to get the generated SQL , then copy this SQL query in a SQL client like DBeaver and run it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and inspect output looking for table scans. You could also use https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/

Comment: Tens of thousands of rows but with a couple joins.  Is there a simple way to override the 30 seconds?  This is for a report that is run very infrequently so I don't really want to spend time optimizing and using 3rd party tools.

Comment: Beyond what you tried I don't know but so far you did not show any log that proves that long query is the issue. If you don't want to optimize the query, you should at least make it asynchronously because otherwise you will hit other timeouts from proxy, browser, ... Building reports synchronously is looking for trouble.